# Is it possible to host a custom UI control inside of MS Word Ribbon

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I have a VSTO add-in for Microsoft Word application. I can easily add controls from Office Ribbon Controls to the ribbon. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-object-model-overview?view=vs-2017) I can also see the list of controls which can be added to the ribbon and all of them implementing `RibbonControl` interface. If for some reasons I want to add a totally custom UI control for example a label control which supports showing a text in different colors - is it possible to accomplish this by implementing `RibbonControl` interface? I have not found any kind of information which could help me to find the answer for this question myself so I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Office Ribbon does not support using custom controls. Only the controls supported by the Ribbon XML specification are allowed.